# Ruby on Rails pushing data into array after looping doesn't save data

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

Created a method to push data into an array, but after I only get the original data, I tried .save but it also doesn't work.

```rb
  def full_qualify_representative(client)
    unless client.customer_types.nil?
      full_rep = [client.capacity] + ["Representado por "]
      # simple array works ok   
      client.customer_types.each do |ct|
        retrieve_represented(ct.represented)
        full_rep << full_qualify(Client.find_by_id(ct.represented))
        # here it works, it comes the original + the new array given by the method full_qualify 
        # tried .save but it doesn't work
      end
      full_rep
      # it returns only the original one 
    end
  end
```

Comment: Not clear on what you mean by "I only get the original data"?  Is `full_rep` a model attribute or something?

Comment: `full_rep` start as an `array` then I put more data on it after the loop => `capacity + representado + 1 2 3 + y z etc . but then i get the information after the loop it came back the original array.

Comment: Update your question to show the debugging you're doing, like copy-paste out of the rails console or irb/pry session.

Answer (score 0):

I think that default `full_rep` is an array. After that, `loop` and add in array.

```
def full_qualify_representative(client)
    full_rep = []
    unless client.customer_types.nil?
      full_rep = [client.capacity] + ["Representado por "]     
      client.customer_types.each do |ct|
        retrieve_represented(ct.represented)
        full_rep << full_qualify(Client.find_by_id(ct.represented))
      end
    end
    full_rep
  end
```

Comment: yes. 

start as an array and I insert more elements with full_qualify and it works 

but when i get the full_rep after the loop I get only the original array back

Comment: The last expression in a conditional is the value of the conditional: `unless false; 5; end #=> 5` - so this change will have no impact.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate my problem with a simple code using only ruby and some simple arrays and it worked well, no bugs. So I figured out it was something I was doing...

This is the code I used to test with simple ruby:

```rb
client = {
  :capacity => ["Capable", "Incapable"],
  :customer_types => ["Capable", "Incapable"],
  :outro => "yes" }


def full_qualify_representative(client)
  unless client[:customer_types].nil?
    full_rep = []
    client[:customer_types].each do |ct|
      full_rep << client[:customer_types]
    end
    full_rep
  end
end

puts full_qualify_representative(client)
```

So I went back to my code and did some manual debugging, and I figured out I was using one method inside another, creating some kind of infinite looping and my code didn't work. I don't know to explain why... but after I removed the looping it worked out.

[image: code]

[image: result1]

[image: result2]